# Add setcontext path in JSR223 sampler in JMeter

Tags: http, jmeter, request, jsr223

I need to add only Context path in my HTTP request through JSR223 sampler.

Is it possible to add only this one or i have to build whole HTTP request?

Answer (score 0):

Add path variable in [JSR223 sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) (or preprocessor defined below the request)

```
 vars.put("path","/your/path");
```

In [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Path field add the variable

```
${path}
```